# If two identical objects (A and B) are dropped from the same height, and B has protective packaging, why is B less likely to be damaged?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, projectile

I know this question has to do with impulse and collision, and if it were in numbers, I could give an answer to it, but how can I explain this in words?

Both object A and B are identical, however, object B has a protective packaging. They are dropped from the same height onto a solid floor without rebounding. How do I explain why object B is less likely to be damaged when dropped?

Answer (score 3):

Both the objects will undergo same change in momentum. That means the impulse will be constant i.e $F\Delta t$ will be constant. Now in this case, the time of impact ($\Delta t$) becomes large due to the protective coating. Therefore $F$ i.e the force with which the body strikes the ground decreases and hence the body is protected.